# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only

Tags: java, jboss7.x, activemq-classic

Hi I am trying to deploying a war file which has activemq-all-5.8.0.jar file in Jboss-as-7.1.1.Final application server. While doing so I am getting following error.

```
    09:55:42,813 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector) Exception in thread "JMX connector" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only
    09:55:42,814 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:126)
    09:55:42,815 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:56)
    09:55:42,816 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:221)
    09:55:42,817 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:161)
    09:55:42,817 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:230)
    09:55:42,818 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
    09:55:42,819 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:643)
    09:55:42,820 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:426)
    09:55:42,820 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext$1.run(ManagementContext.java:131)
    09:55:44,826 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector) Exception in thread "JMX connector" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only
    09:55:44,827 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:126)
    09:55:44,828 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:56)
    09:55:44,828 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:221)
    09:55:44,829 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:161)
    09:55:44,842 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:230)
    09:55:44,842 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:419)
    09:55:44,843 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:643)
    09:55:44,844 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:426)
    09:55:44,844 ERROR [stderr] (JMX connector)     at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext$1.run(ManagementContext.java:131)
```

The application getting deployed successfully though and also works as intended.
Can any one please help in resolving this
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have struck upon this particular link [AS7-2755](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2755), but this not making any sence to me

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old but the following information is still useful:

Starting an activemq broker in JBOSS is quite reasonable. The error is occurring because the broker is being started in JBOSS, but the broker has a management context that has

`<amq:managementContext>
        <amq:managementContext createConnector="true" />
    </amq:managementContext>`

This is the default behaviour, so if you have not configured this, then you will need to. There are reasons why you may want to create your own connector, for instance if you are running a broker standalone, but if you're running in a JBOSS container then it's likely that you won't want to, you can just use theirs.

You can also turn it off for all brokers in the jvm by setting the system property:

`-Dorg.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.createConnector=false`

You may still get this error even though you think you have configured the JMS connector to `false` on the broker. It happened when I created connection factories using the broker url `vm://localhost` and used them to create connections before the properly configured broker was started. As far as I could tell in my case a broker with default settings was automatically created for the connection. This was not anything to do with ActiveMQ, it was just a race condition when creating brokers on one thread and connections on another.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you start an activemq broker (server) from within your war:

```
org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext$1.run(ManagementContext.java:131)
```

I would guess that this is not what you want. You probably use activemq just as client? If this is the case, you should include only the client-libraries.

Comment: No I am not using as a client but as a server, I need to create various queues using the same

Comment: But then you shouldn't deploy a JMS server in a war file. Either you use the JMS-server that comes with JBoss (HornetQ) or you include the ActiveMQ broker via JCA (RAR-adapter). I'm not sure whether ActiveMQ works with AS7.1.1 (I don't think so), it works with EAP6.1 (tried it) and higher (supported with 6.2) and I guess with WildFly8.